# GeoServer - WMS CQL_FILTER id = 'XXX' works but id IN ('XXX') does not

Tags: geoserver, wms, cql-filter, getmap

I have a WMS that I need to filter with CQL_FILTER parameter using an array of srting IDs.

The layer is published from a PostGIS Table View which is declared like so:

```
create view mob.daily_origin_all
as select "date", "start", "end", id, inc, totinc, diaginc, offdiaginc, mob.calculateSignalLevel(inc) as "level", country, wkb_geometry as geom from
    (select "date", "start", "end", origin as id, sum(inc) inc, avg(totinc) totinc, avg(diaginc) diaginc, avg(offdiaginc) offdiaginc, max(country) country
    from mob.signals
    where freq = 'daily'
    group by "date", "start", "end", origin) as dlorgall,
    mob.geo
where zone_id = dlorgall.id;
```

In the GeoServer Layer Preview page, I can try to apply a CQL_FILTER parameter.

Supposing the `id` I am looking for is `XXX`, when I do `id = 'XXX'` I receive the correct response and can visualize the area I need in the map.

However, when I try with `id IN ('XXX')`, I receive an empty image. So, it seems the request is correct but the result is empty, when it should be equal to the one given by `id = 'XXX'`.

I also looked at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340960/i-cannot-make-the-cql-parameter-in-work), but it did not help apparently.

And, when I look at the GeoServer log, I see this warning:

```
WARNING: ID IN (...) is a deprecated syntax, you should use IN (...)
```

So I am guessing this is a matter of naming the column differently than `id`. But why should it work in one way and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's a matter of wrapping `id` with double quotes.

`"id" IN ('XXX')` works fine.

I guess `ID` is a special name reserved for GeoServer tables, so this way the system knows its the actual name of a column in my layer.

Answer (score 0):

`id` appears to be interpreted as an internal keyword for FeatureID and not a property/attribute/column name. Many datasets will use `id` as a column name and might get tripped up by this.

Example, using the topp:states layer in the default data:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=topp:states&outputFormat=json

[image: image.png]

Here, `id` is the FeatureID = `states.49` and thus http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=topp:states&outputFormat=json&cql_filter=id+IN+('states.49') will return this one result.

However, if we customise the attributes and change attribute `STATE_NAME` to `id`, simulating a non-index database column called `id`:

[image]

then http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=topp:states&outputFormat=json&cql_filter=id+IN+('Washington') will not match the record, as `id` is being used as the FeatureID.  In order to use the column `id`, we need to put it in double quotes:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=topp:states&outputFormat=json&cql_filter="id"+IN+('Washington'), and this then works, as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373006/68995

Simply using the IN(filter) format: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=topp:states&outputFormat=json&cql_filter=IN+('Washington'), implies the FeatureID `id` and does not return any data.

The XML equivalent: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=json&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%3E%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3Eid%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3EWashington%3C%2FLiteral%3E%3C%2FPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C%2FFilter%3E (which encodes this filter, for those of us who can't easily URL-decode in our heads:

```
  <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
     <PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <PropertyName>id</PropertyName>
       <Literal>Washington</Literal>
     </PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </Filter>
```

)
does correctly use the attribute `id`, as expected, and not the FeatureID `id`.

According to the both https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html and https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html,

[image: image.png]
and
[image: image.png]
it appears as though we should be able to filter on attribute `id` =  Washington rather than FeatureID `id` = states.49

I think the best way forward is to simply document that an attribute `id` is special and needs to be quoted thus: "id", which I will do.

EDIT: Andrea (core developer) clarified that `id` is indeed special, because it is a [reserved keyword](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/cql/src/main/jjtree/ECQLGrammar.jjt#L180) in ECQL.